# Type of Lyapunov surfaces corresponding to a specific Lyapunov function

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, mathematics, geometry, nonlinear-control

Consider the following Lyapunov candidate function:

$$ V(x,y,q_i) = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{2}y^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln\big(\cosh(q_{i})\big) \tag1$$

where $q_{i} = \sqrt{(x-x_{i})^2 + (y-y_{i})^2} - L, \ L>0 \ (\text{constant})$, $n\geq1$ is an arbitrary positive integer number. The symbols $x,y\in \mathbb{R} $ are scalars representing the position of a rigid body in 2D space. The positive integer $n$ corresponds to the number of other units in the 2D space, the position of which is known. So, the pairs $(x_i, y_i), i=1,\dots,n$ represent the positions of $n$ bodies in the 2D space. Consequently, the summation term denotes the potential energy of the system with $(x_i,y_i)$ being known.

I would like to understand what does the function $V(x,y,q_i)$ represent for different values of the arguments $x,y$ in the 2D space. If there wasn't the summation term, then it would certainly represent a circle in the 2D space. I am not sure about its representation in the above case where the summation term exists. Does it still represent a circle (or an ellipse) with different radius and center than the case without the summation term ?

What I am looking for, is to understand the type of the Lyapunov surfaces (level surfaces) defined by equation (1). It should be noted that (1) possesses the characteristics of Lyapunov functions:

1. $V(x,y,q_i) = 0$ if and only if $(x,y,q_i) = 0$.
2. $V(\cdot)$ is a positive continuously differentiable function satisfying $V(x,y,q_i) > 0 \ \forall (x,y,q_i)\neq (0,0,0)$.

Comment: A few points: **1** $q_i$ is *not* an independent variable; it has (hidden) dependence on $x,y$. **2** Does your candidate Lyapunov function sastisfy **all** required pre requisites (like positive definiteness)? points 1&2 are not enough IMO **3** Describe all variables. e.g. are $x,y$ scalars? what do $x_i, y_i$ represent etc. What is $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Added some explanation. What else do you think should hold for $V$ ? I mean, it's $0$ only if its arguments are $0$ and otherwise positive.